# Ember nested route not work properly

Tags: ember.js

i am very new to Ember
I have a template which has the list of categories.  When i click on a link in the list a nested template is correctly showing. When i click another category  the URL correctly changes but nested template not updated
My router:

```
Router.map(function() {

  this.route('subcategory', { path: "/:sub_id"}, function() {
    this.route('items', { path: "/:item_id"  })
  });

});
```

Parent template:

```
<div class="todo">
            <ul class="todo-list">
              {{#each model as |category|}}
              <li>

                <span class="desc">{{category.title}}</span>
    <span class="label label-info" >    {{#link-to 'subcategory.items' category.id }}<i class="fa fa-barcode" ></i>{{/link-to}} </span>


              </li>
              {{/each}}

            </ul>
          </div>
{{outlet}}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks !

Comment: In console, what was the error you are getting ?..

Comment: Where is `category` route in router.js? And what is the name of your parent template?

Comment: No error in the console. in nested route i am use jquery datatable

Comment: Throw some more code so that we can provide the answer you are looking for